# javascript iterating algorithm accept half of the scores from array which should rejected

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to check whether my variable is an array and if its elements contain substrings with '.png' or '.jpg'. So I wrote this code:

```
let test = ['empty_250x380@3x.png',
'empty_250x380@3x.png',
'empty_250x380@3x.png',
'empty_250x380@3x.png',
'empty_250x380@3x.png','empty_250x380@3x.png']

if(Array.isArray(test))
{
   for(let n in test)
   {
     if(test[n].includes('.png') || test[n].includes('.PNG') || test[n].includes('.jpg') || test[n].includes('.JPG') )
     {
        test.splice(n,1);
     }
   } 
     console.log(test.length); // here is 3
  };
```

But it always let pass every even index of the array so I get half of the scores wrong. I have no idea how it is even possible. Do you know how can I fix it?

Comment: Modifying the array over which you're iterating is bound to cause bugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the iteration is that index is going from `0 to 5` while `splice`ing array. When the index reaches 3rd element, size of array becomes `3` and hence `test[3]`, `test[4]` and `test[5]` is not defined. That is why you are getting the size as `3`. Try iterating from `5` to `0`, eg:

```js
let test = ['empty_250x380@3x.png',  'empty_250x380@3x.png',  'empty_250x380@3x.png',  'empty_250x380@3x.png',  'empty_250x380@3x.png', 'empty_250x380@3x.png'];

if(Array.isArray(test)) {
  for(let n = test.length - 1; n >= 0; n--) {
    if(test[n].includes('.png') || test[n].includes('.PNG') || test[n].includes('.jpg') || test[n].includes('.JPG')) {
      test.splice(n, 1);
    }
  } 
  console.log(test.length);
};
```

Alternatively, you can use regex for reducing your code:

```js
let test = ['empty_250x380@3x.png',  'empty_250x380@3x.png',  'empty_250x380@3x.png',  'empty_250x380@3x.png',  'empty_250x380@3x.png', 'empty_250x380@3x.png'];

if(Array.isArray(test)) {
  for(let n = test.length - 1; n >= 0; n--) {
    if(/\.(png|jpg)$/i.test(test[n])) {
      test.splice(n, 1);
    }
  } 
  console.log(test.length);
};
```

A better version:

```js
let test = ['empty_250x380@3x.png',  'empty_250x380@3x.png',  'empty_250x380@3x.png',  'empty_250x380@3x.png',  'empty_250x380@3x.png', 'empty_250x380@3x.png'];

if(Array.isArray(test)) {
  console.log(test.filter(e => ! /\.(png|jpg|svg)$/i.test(e)).length);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

That approach is modifying the current array, leading to cause an error regarding to the current index.

**An alternative is executing a reverse loop because the main problem is the visited indexes:**

```js
let test = ['empty_250x380@3x.png',  'empty_250x380@3x.png',  'empty_250x380@3x.png',  'empty_250x380@3x.png',  'empty_250x380@3x.png', 'empty_250x380@3x.png'];

if (Array.isArray(test)) {
  var n = test.length;
  while (n--) {
    if (test[n].includes('.png') || test[n].includes('.PNG') || test[n].includes('.jpg') || test[n].includes('.JPG')) {
      test.splice(n, 1);
      console.log(test);
    }
  }
  console.log(test.length); // here is 3
};
```

**Recommendation:**  Get the extension of every image and use the function `Array.prototype.includes`

```js
let test = ['empty_250x380@3x.png',  'empty_250x380@3x.png',  'empty_250x380@3x.png',  'empty_250x380@3x.png',  'empty_250x380@3x.png', 'empty_250x380@3x.png'],
    allowedExts = ['.png', '.jpg'];

if (Array.isArray(test)) {
  var n = test.length;
  while (n--) {
    var ext = test[n].substring(test[n].lastIndexOf('.')).toLowerCase();
    if (allowedExts.includes(ext)) test.splice(n, 1);
  }
  console.log(test.length);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do it check if `Array.isArray` and then make sure that `every` element of the `array` ends with `.png` or .`jpg`

```js
let test = ['empty_250x380@3x.png',
'empty_250x380@3x.png',
'empty_250x380@3x.png',
'empty_250x380@3x.jpg',
'empty_250x380@3x.png','empty_250x380@3x.png']

function check(arr) {
   return Array.isArray(arr) && arr.every(i=>['.jpg','.png'].indexOf(i.slice(-4))!== - 1)
}
console.log(check(test))
```

Answer (score 1):

You might have more success using some of the nice Array methods. For this you'd use filter to remove the items you don't want. Bonus of this being it's immutable so it returns a new array with just the items you want. It also looks much better in my opinion.

```
const acceptableItems = test.filter(filename => {
    // keep the item in the array if it includes png
    return filename.includes('png') ... 

    // OR. remove it from the new array if it includes png
    return !filename.includes('png')
})
```

Answer (score 1):

This seem like a good use case for a simple regex and `every()`. The regex allows the test to anchor to the end of the line so it shouldn't match a case like 'empty.pngstuff.txt', which `includes()` will match. And it's very readable.

```js
let test_array = ['empty_250x380@3x.png',
'empty_250x380@3x.png',
'empty_250x380@3x.PNG',
'empty_250x380@3x.jpeg',
'pngempty_250x380@3x.png','empty_250x380@3x.png'
]

// i modifier makes it case insensitive
let re =  RegExp(/.(png|jpeg)$/i)

let result = Array.isArray(test_array) 
             && test_array.every(i => re.test(i))

console.log(result)
```